# How can I model a custom exception association in a class diagram?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Reading [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62790), it seems modelling a custom exception class using a generalisation is common place. What it doesn't mention is how I can model an association with a class that could potentially throw the custom exception. Note, I'm not asking how to model the sequence behaviour when it comes to raising the exception; I'm specifically wanting to model the association. Or is this a misuse of the class diagram?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably like this:

[image]

Note that `<<throws>>` isn't a standard UML stereotype.  There's nothing wrong with that - it's perfectly fine to define your own.  If you want to stick to standards though, `<<create>>` is probably the closest.  (See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/rrelstereo.html) for list of supported stereotypes as at UML 2.1).

You *could* model MyClass-MyException as a simple binary association rather than a dependency but it doesn't really hold semantically; there's no systematic relationship among them.  Similar to the case where a Factory creates instances.  There's a good article on Dependency relationships [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5JSH_9.0.0/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html) if you need more info.

> is this a misuse of the class diagram?

Not if you find it useful.  UML is a tool: use it where & how it helps, ignore it where it doesn't.  Case in point: pedantically, `MyClass` doesn't throw any exceptions, one or more methods of `MyClass` throws the Exception.  So the dependency is an abstraction.  However as long as:

- you - and whomever else needs to read the model - understands that, and
- it's useful

then it's not misuse, it's use.

hth.

Comment: good answer - question, how does a binary associatioin represent this relationship? `MyException` doesn't necessarily know of the existence of `MyClass`?

Comment: Good point, that's another reason why a binary assoc isn't really appropriate.  I only mentioned Binary Assoc to illustrate why it's *not* the right way to model it (even though binaries are probably the most common relationships).

Comment: Is multiplicity relevant here, to illustrate for example that the class can throw unrestricted amount of exceptions?