# How to express exceptions in the method declaration in UML class diagram?

Tags: exception, uml, class-diagram

I have used UML for some time, and got a basic handle on it. But sometimes I realize the need of expressing the exception a declared method might throw in the class diagram. Anyone knows is it after all possible? or if possible how?

Answer (score 2):

How to model a static model for exceptions is shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074664/how-can-i-model-a-custom-exception-association-in-a-class-diagram).

What you are asking is also about behavior. This is not expressed in a class diagram which only shows static relations. Exceptions are shown either in activity or in sequence diagrams.

To begin with the latter:

[image]

Here an `alt` fragment is used where the upper part shows the exception behavior and the lower part the normal result. Note that this is a simple on-the-fly sketch.

In an activity diagram you show it like this:

[image]

`Action` corresponds to a method in a class (given in brackets below the name). It's inside an `InterruptibleRegion` and an `InterruptFlow` goes to an input pin of an exception handler (transporting the exception information).

Comment: The answer this SO answer. uses a stereotype throw which I did not find in the specification 2.5, do I miss something ?

Comment: @granier You are free to "invent" your own stereotypes. This seems to be an appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

In the UML, an exception is a specialization of a signal, which is the specification of an asynchronous communication between objects. This means that in interaction diagrams, exceptions are illustrated as asynchronous messages.

The following diagram (from this [book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/applying-uml-and-patterns-an-introduction-to-object-oriented-analysis-and-design-and-the-unified-process/oclc/1031400979)) shows an example of exceptions in an interaction diagram.

[image: Handling Failure]